# Author of the Content

Tags: content

I would like to display author of the content for each page in the sharepoint web application in the footer for each page. Please let me know how do I acheieve this?

Thanks
Ram

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by custom web part.

Create a custom web part and add it to your master page.
To get the author from your page, in your custom web part use:

```
SPContext.Current.Item["Author"];
```

or

```
SPContext.Current.ListItem["Author"];
```